# Can one initialize a Java string with a single repeated character to a specific length

Tags: java, string, initialization

I'd like to create a function that has the following signature:

```
public String createString(int length, char ch)
```

It should return a string of repeating characters of the specified length.
For example if length is 5 and ch is 'p' the return value should be:

> ppppp

Is there a way to do this without looping until it is the required length?
And without any externally defined constants?

Comment: It does look like a duplicate question, but the answers here are much nicer :)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```java
char[] chars = new char[len];
Arrays.fill(chars, ch);
String s = new String(chars);
```

Comment: Really simple and helpful.

Answer (score 41):

[`StringUtils.repeat(str, count)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat(char,%20int)) from apache commons-lang

Comment: Perfect! Why write three lines when you can write 1?

Comment: @deGoot, cause you need third-party library for that

Comment: which you probably already have.. :)

Comment: @Bozho not rly.....

Answer (score 30):

Here is an elegant, pure Java, one-line solution:

Java 11+:

```java
String str = "p".repeat(5); // "ppppp"
```

prior Java 11:

```java
String str = new String(new char[5]).replace("\0", "p"); // "ppppp"
```

Comment: Seeing all the solutions, I wonder whether `String` should have a constructor like `String(int size, char filler)` or a method `fillWith(char filler)`.

Answer (score 8):

For the record, with Java8 you can do that with streams:

```
String p10times = IntStream.range(0, 10)
  .mapToObj(x -> "p")
  .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

But this seems somewhat overkill.

Comment: Upvoted for coolness.

Comment: To avoid generating and discarding the IntStream values `String p10Times = Stream.generate(() -> "p").limit(10).collect(Collectors.joining());`

Answer (score 1):

Bit more advance and readable ,

```
 public static String repeat(int len, String ch) {

        String s = IntStream.generate(() -> 1).limit(len).mapToObj(x -> ch).collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println("s " + s);
        return s;    
    }
```