# I want to display letter 'z' for each character in a String user enters

Tags: java, android

My problem is this. I need to make a String that is composed of letters 'z'. For example, if a user enters a word "goodbye" i want to display the String "zzzzzzz", for word "house" it would be "zzzzz" and so on. Can someone pls help me with this method.

Comment: `str.replaceAll(".", "z")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900477/can-one-initialise-a-java-string-with-a-single-repeated-character-to-a-specific). Here's an example of one way to do it that preserves the original string.

```
String makeZs(String in) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); ++i) {
        b.append("z");
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Comment: `String.repeat()` is introduced in Java 11, which isn't released yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use regex, take a look at this [regex cheatsheet](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/):

```
String myWord = "hello";

String newWord = myWord.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "z");

// prints zzzzz
System.out.println(newWord);
```

So this will only switch out each letter for z in your output

Answer (score 1):

I assume u want to replace all user input with 'z' when a user inserts a letter you want to convert it into z and show it on edit text. then follow the code below.

```
et = findViewById(R.id.et);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String s = new String ();
            for(int k = 0; k<charSequence.length(); k++){
            s = s+'z';
          }
          et.setText(s) //charSequence is user current input


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: No, I want to add a method that passes a String as an argument and returnes String made of 'z' with the same length

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
public String toZstring(String userString){

    String zString = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++){
        zString = zString + "z";
    }

    return zString;

}
```

Comment: It's for android. To get the text the user typed out. I removed it since it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: I missed the android tag actually.